# GoogleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName(String) not working on Android 6.0 without Contacts permission

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm retrieving an GoogleAccountCredential object using:

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                context, Arrays.asList({ GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM }))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
                .setSelectedAccountName(email)
```

with email being the Gmail account I'm using on the device.

If I retrieve the account name using credential.getSelectedAccountName the result is null.

This happens only on devices running Android Marshmallow and only if the app does NOT have the Contacts permission. As soon as I grant the Contacts permission everything works.

Why would GoogleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName(String) require the Contacts permission? Is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"contacts permission group" is required because  the get_account permission required for getselectedaccountname is grouped under contacts.

that is according to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: And the solution is: 1) request the contact permission or 2) set the targetSdkVersion to 22 instead of 23. Android should have a finer grained permission model...

Comment: For android M(6) forward make sure the permission is toggled. By default the application wont have permission even if you specify it.